# python time since epoch hacking system variable

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out whether it's safe to let a payed software check its own license date validity using the client's computer

the way this is done is by invoking time.time() function from python and comparing it to the hashed license expiry date. if the time.time() returns anything after the expiry date than the software throws a license expired error.

The concern I have is whether it's possible for someone to change some system variables and get time.time() function return a different difference since epoch than the real actual one.

thanks

Comment: Probably better to ask here: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Surely there are websites such as nist.time.gov from which you can get date and time info. See: https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/services/internet-time-service-its

Comment: The end user can always block connections to nist.gov (or some other web API) or edit the executable to remove the check. It's a cat and mouse game and theoretically you can never win, it's just a question of how many hoops you make someone jump through to disable the check. [Software cracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_cracking) has a long history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time.time() value is returning in python by the operating system time that is getting and setting by GetSystemTime and SetSystemTime of the C library so it can be altered by the user with the right privileges. To ask a web API will be a better approach of checking expiration date that not depending on the operating system time.